# Does this question belong here?

Tags: discussion, support

On cogsci there was migrated a question from academia. I think it better fits here I could be wrong but the design looks like a multivariable feed forward neural network. 
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6026/what-do-we-call-the-middle-variables-in-a-complex-research-model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the best fit, but it is about understanding the parts of a path model.  (It isn't an artificial neural network.)  Path models are part of statistics, so it can be migrated here.